# change master page

Tags: master-page

I have designed a master page and deployed it to the master page gallery on my sharepoint site.

When I set the site to use this master page everything looks correct, however when I create a new site it defaults back to using v4.master.

Can anyone please point me in the direction I need to take so that I can always use my master page?

Thanks, Marc

Answer (score 2):

Did you click "Set as default masterpage" in SharePoint Designer (assuming you used SPD to develop the masterpage)?

Answer (score 1):

You can do "reset all subsites to use current masterpage" but that will not help for new sites.
If the new site is set to inherit the masterpage then it should be fine.

Thanks
Matt